# Moving navbar from the right to the left

Tags: css, navbar

I am trying to move my horizontal menu from right to the left, but I can't find any good solution to do. 
[this is how the menu currently looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfQSs.png)

This is the code that is use for navigation bar:

```
 .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        min-height: 125px;
        margin-bottom: 0!important;
        text-align: justify
    }

    .navbar-collapse ul li a {
        font-family: {{ settings.face_secondary_button_text }};
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: {{ settings.color_secondary_button_text }};
        font-weight: 900;
        height: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 22px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 55px;


    }

    .navbar-collapse ul li a:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 3px solid {{ settings.color_secondary_button_hover }};
    }

    .on-state {
        background-color: transparent!important;
        border-bottom: 3px solid {{ settings.color_body_text }}!important;
    }

    .navbar-static-top {
      margin-bottom: 0!important;
      min-height: 80px;
    }
```

Comment: please share live link or demo where we can see issue in live then we can help..by little bit part of code we cant help.

Comment: It is on this link: www.givemeiceland.com

Comment: anand already solved your issue so just change the class navbar-left to navbar-right and all will be ok..:)

Answer (score 0):

there will be a ul class="navbar-left" in the navbar section u have the menu in the "navbar-right" change the menu into  navbar-right or refer bootstrap 3 navbar.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a direct access to all CSS, only style2.css sheet.

Comment: i have seen ur site, please review again there is mistakes in the css(style2.css). u have used the class="container", but the menu is outside the container.

Comment: U can use logo and menu as float instead of using display: table-cell.    for menu a remove height: 2px and use padding and margin to control the menu.